# AudioKit unexpected crash ios with swift on AKOscillator - [AKOscillator operationName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

I am receiving a strange crash when using AudioKit to build a Swift based ios 8 application. I followed all the videos and am able to successfully build and launch an AudioKit based project using the bridging header, etc. Now in my main ViewController, I have just the following code based on the **hello world** example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let inst = AKInstrument()

  //let oscillator = AKOscillator()
  //inst.setAudioOutput(oscillator)
  //AKOrchestra.addInstrument(inst)
  //inst.play()
}
```

That runs fine, but the second that I uncomment the lines below initializing the AKInstrument, I get a crash shortly after my app launches:

```
    0dBFS level = 32768.0
    Csound version 6.05 (float samples) Aug  6 2015
    libsndfile-1.0.26pre6
        2015-10-22 11:19:15.024 NILG5[1281:37425] 1 MIDI sources
    2015-10-22 11:19:15.025 NILG5[1281:37425] MIDI source 0: Session 1
    440.0
    2015-10-22 11:19:16.072 NILG5[1281:36836] -[AKOscillator operationName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb6904b78b0
    2015-10-22 11:19:16.160 NILG5[1281:36836] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AKOscillator operationName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb6904b78b0'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110094c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111c64bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011009c0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fff213c ___forwarding___ + 988
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fff1cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
        5   NILG5                               0x000000010f43d14b -[AKOscillator init] + 43
        6   NILG5                               0x000000010f430790 _TTOFCSo12AKOscillatorcfMS_FT_S_ + 16
        7   NILG5                               0x000000010f42c2c7 _TFCSo12AKOscillatorCfMS_FT_S_ + 71
        8   NILG5                               0x000000010f42b564 _TFC5NILG514ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 308
        9   NILG5                               0x000000010f42b6e2 _TToFC5NILG514ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
        10  UIKit                               0x0000000110ac91d0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
        11  UIKit                               0x0000000110ac93ce -[UIViewController view] + 27
        12  UIKit                               0x00000001109e4289 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
        13  UIKit                               0x00000001109e464f -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
        14  UIKit                               0x00000001109f0de1 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
        15  UIKit                               0x0000000110994417 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
        16  UIKit                               0x000000011099719e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
        17  UIKit                               0x0000000110996095 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
        18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116ce95e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ffc841c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ffbe165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ffbdf25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ffbd366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
        23  UIKit                               0x0000000110995b02 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
        24  UIKit                               0x00000001109988c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
        25  NILG5                               0x000000010f430ee7 main + 135
        26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001123a6145 start + 1
        27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Seems like its complaining about `[AKOscillator operationName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb6904b78b0` ... but the docs clearly allow you to initialize an `AKOscillator` without any parameters...

Not sure, any ideas??